# Proving De Morgan laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

question is from Apostol's Vol. 1 One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

*Page 16. Exercise 19.* Let $\mathscr F$ be a class of sets. Then $$B-\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr F}A=\bigcap_{A\in\mathscr F}(B-A)$$and$$B-\bigcap_{A\in\mathscr F}A=\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr F}(B-A).$$

*The attempt at a solution:* All I could do is to expand what is written in the first question: $$B-(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n)=(B-A_1)\cap(B-A_2)\cap\cdots\cap(B-A_n).$$Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: One very helpful way to prove that two sets are equal, is to prove that each set contains the other. So show that if $x \in $LHS then $x\in $RHS and visa versa.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, that's how I solved most of the other 18 exercises, I guess i missed something, will try again.

Comment: Not 24 hours ago someone posted another essentially duplicate question to the question "DeMorgan laws in the infinite case"...

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you, your answer to that other (pretty much the same) question helped me a lot!